# Run JavaScript code in SandBox safely

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, sandbox

I'm trying to run JavaScript code in a safely SandBox server-side.

I'm working on a "server" builder, I want to let users run their own JavaScript without compromising my server.

I've tried: `npm sandbox` but it is not that efficient for running too many codes simultaneously.

I just want something like `eval();` but with no risk of running malicious code.

I've also read there is this `npm vm`, but it's kinda tricky to run it safely, I need to create a file for every JavaScript code and run it with `child_procces`, but I don't find it too convenient for my case. Users are modifying `JavaScript` on the go/changing it "live". Plus the codes could be executed thousands of times per hour, it is a chatbot server, gotta execute the JavaScript codes everytime a user sends a message.

Comment: What kind of Scripts do you want to allow to be run on your server? Why not run them on the client?

Comment: @Thomas Client is Facebook Messenger App (it is for chatbots), so I can't run it on the client, must be run on the server. I receive the message, then run script, and then output message to reply. I just need to run simple codes, ifs, fors, comparisons, simple algorithms.